# How to Add Layer in React Leaflet & Routing Machine and Filter by Vehicle Code

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3, react-leaflet-v4

[image]

You can see the component I created in the picture. Here are the different vehicles and their latitude and longitude values. I am routing according to these values. What I want to add at this stage is that there is a layer button on the top right of the map and I want my vehicle codes in the popup that opens when I click on this layer button. Vehicle24, Vehicle30... When I click on vehicle24 from the popup that opens, I want only vehicle24's routes to appear. Is this possible, I can't make any progress. Thanks in advance for your help. I will add the codes I used below

**TrackingMap.tsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
//Third Party imports
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';

//Components imports
import Routing from './Routing';

//Utils import
import { MapWithPopupdatav2 } from './fakeData2';
import { CoordinatInterface, EachPointforRouting } from 'types/Map';

interface DefaultMapWithPopupProps {
  // dataSource: RootMapWithPopupData;
  height?: string;
  width?: string;
}

const TrackingMap = ({ height }: DefaultMapWithPopupProps) => {
  const [markersDataSource, setMarkersDataSource] = useState(
    MapWithPopupdatav2.data.map(item => item.gridData.data.map(item => item))
  );

  const [routeWayColor, setRouteWayColor] = useState<string[]>(
    MapWithPopupdatav2.data.map(item => item.color)
  );

  const [dataForRouting, setDataForRouting] = useState<EachPointforRouting[][]>(
    MapWithPopupdatav2.data.map(eachPoint =>
      eachPoint.gridData.data.map(point =>
        L.latLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)
      )
    )
  );

  const markersLatLon: CoordinatInterface[][] = MapWithPopupdatav2.data.map(
    eachPoint =>
      eachPoint.gridData.data.map(point => ({
        latitude: point.latitude,
        longitude: point.longitude,
      }))
  );
  function centerMapDataCalculate(data: CoordinatInterface[][]) {
    let newArray: CoordinatInterface[] = [];
    data.forEach(item => {
      item.map(point => {
        newArray.push(point);
      });
    });
    return newArray;
  }

  const markersCoordinatesForMapCentering: CoordinatInterface[] =
    centerMapDataCalculate(markersLatLon);
  return (
    <MapContainer scrollWheelZoom={true} style={{ height: `${height}` }}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {dataForRouting.map((eachPoint, index) => {
        return (
          <Routing
            key={index}
            eachPoint={eachPoint}
            dataSource={markersDataSource[index]}
            color={routeWayColor[index]}
            bounds={markersCoordinatesForMapCentering}
          />
        );
      })}
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default TrackingMap;
```

**Routing.tsx**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
//Third Party İmports
import L, { latLngBounds } from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css';
import 'leaflet-routing-machine';
import { useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
//Components

//Utils import
import { RoutingPropsforTrackingMap } from 'types/Map';
import { MarkerSVG } from 'utils/markerSVG';
import { closePopUpIconOptions } from 'utils/closePopUpIconOptions';
import { layerGroup } from 'leaflet';

L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
});

const Routing = ({
  eachPoint,
  dataSource,
  color,
  bounds,
}: RoutingPropsforTrackingMap) => {
  const map = useMap();
  let markerBounds = latLngBounds([]);
  const svgIcon = (visitOrder: number, color: string) =>
    L.divIcon({
      html: MarkerSVG(visitOrder, color),
      className: 'markerIcon',
      iconSize: [50, 50],
      iconAnchor: [32, 70],
      popupAnchor: [0, -70],
    });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;
    console.log(eachPoint);

    const routingControl = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: eachPoint,
      createMarker: function (
        waypointIndex: any,
        waypoint: any,
        numberOfWaypoints: any
      ) {
        return L.marker(waypoint.latLng, {
          icon: svgIcon(dataSource[waypointIndex].visitOrder, color),
        })
          .bindPopup(
            `<p><b>Location Code:</b>${dataSource[waypointIndex].locationCode}</p>
          <p><b>Location Type:</b>${dataSource[waypointIndex].locationType}</p>
          <p><b>Visit Order:</b>${dataSource[waypointIndex].visitOrder}</p>
          <p><b>Vehicle Code:</b>${dataSource[waypointIndex].vehicleCode}</p>
          `
          )
          .on('click', function (e: any) {
            closePopUpIconOptions();
          });
      },
      lineOptions: {
        styles: [
          {
            color: color,
            opacity: 1,
            weight: 7,
          },
        ],
      },

      addWaypoints: false,
      draggableWaypoints: false,
      fitSelectedRoutes: false,
      showAlternatives: true,
    }).addTo(map);
    if (bounds.length && bounds.length > 0) {
      bounds.forEach(marker => {
        markerBounds.extend([marker.latitude, marker.longitude]);
      });
      map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
    }

    return () => map.removeControl(routingControl);
  }, [map]);

  return null;
};
export default Routing;
```

**FakeData.ts**

```
export const MapWithPopupdatav2 = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      vehicleCode: 'Vehicle39',
      vehicleId: 39,
      color: '#0ac282',
      gridData: {
        currentPage: 1,
        firstRowOnPage: 1,
        kind: 0,
        lastRowOnPage: 15,
        pageCount: 1,
        pageSize: 10000,
        totalRowCount: 15,
        data: [
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 245046421,
            duration: 618000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T11:44:39',
            latitude: 41.021569,
            locationCode: 'S1R1037',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'RCM',
            longitude: 29.040992,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 116894,
            serviceType: 'RCM Replenish',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T11:34:21',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle39',
            vehicleId: 39,
            visitOrder: 1,
          },
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 189364956,
            duration: 1074000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T12:05:35',
            latitude: 41.018218,
            locationCode: 'S1A2275',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'RCM',
            longitude: 29.044254,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 116906,
            serviceType: 'Fix',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T11:47:41',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle39',
            vehicleId: 39,
            visitOrder: 2,
          },
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 189452735,
            duration: 618000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T12:47:52',
            latitude: 41.0075,
            locationCode: 'S1R2054',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'RCM',
            longitude: 29.035592,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 116891,
            serviceType: 'RCM Replenish',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T12:37:34',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle39',
            vehicleId: 39,
            visitOrder: 3,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      vehicleCode: 'Vehicle24',
      vehicleId: 24,
      color: '#807ACD',
      gridData: {
        currentPage: 1,
        firstRowOnPage: 1,
        kind: 0,
        lastRowOnPage: 6,
        pageCount: 1,
        pageSize: 10000,
        totalRowCount: 6,
        data: [
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 245857071,
            duration: 696000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T12:13:45',
            latitude: 40.999569,
            locationCode: '0405',
            locationName: 'Branch48',
            locationType: 'Branch',
            longitude: 29.095666,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117530,
            serviceType: 'Cash pickup & Delivery',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T12:02:09',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle24',
            vehicleId: 24,
            visitOrder: 1,
          },
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 276074744,
            duration: 696000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T14:11:36',
            latitude: 40.992341,
            locationCode: '0022',
            locationName: 'Branch10',
            locationType: 'Branch',
            longitude: 29.101693,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117529,
            serviceType: 'Cash pickup & Delivery',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T14:00:00',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle24',
            vehicleId: 24,
            visitOrder: 2,
          },
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 242141750,
            duration: 696000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T16:11:36',
            latitude: 40.98491,
            locationCode: '0610',
            locationName: 'Branch70',
            locationType: 'Branch',
            longitude: 29.092627,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117528,
            serviceType: 'Cash pickup & Delivery',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T16:00:00',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle24',
            vehicleId: 24,
            visitOrder: 3,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      vehicleCode: 'Vehicle36',
      vehicleId: 24,
      color: '#F38876',
      gridData: {
        currentPage: 1,
        firstRowOnPage: 1,
        kind: 0,
        lastRowOnPage: 28,
        pageCount: 1,
        pageSize: 10000,
        totalRowCount: 28,
        data: [
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 245046567,
            duration: 1074000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T11:38:01',
            latitude: 40.980517,
            locationCode: 'S1A4960',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'ATM',
            longitude: 29.075156,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117282,
            serviceType: 'Fix',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T11:20:07',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle36',
            vehicleId: 36,
            visitOrder: 1,
          },
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 189328693,
            duration: 444000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T11:49:35',
            latitude: 40.979788,
            locationCode: 'S1A7396',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'ATM',
            longitude: 29.067378,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117281,
            serviceType: 'ATM Replenish',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T11:42:11',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle36',
            vehicleId: 36,
            visitOrder: 2,
          },
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 191205228,
            duration: 1074000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T12:14:55',
            latitude: 40.974639,
            locationCode: 'S1A9243',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'RCM',
            longitude: 29.05792,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117280,
            serviceType: 'Fix',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T11:57:01',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle36',
            vehicleId: 36,
            visitOrder: 3,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      vehicleCode: 'Vehicle30',
      vehicleId: 30,
      color: '#008EA9',
      gridData: {
        currentPage: 1,
        firstRowOnPage: 1,
        kind: 0,
        lastRowOnPage: 23,
        pageCount: 1,
        pageSize: 10000,
        totalRowCount: 23,
        data: [
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 271855562,
            duration: 618000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T12:46:37',
            latitude: 41.025808,
            locationCode: 'S1R2206',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'RCM',
            longitude: 29.015655,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117165,
            serviceType: 'RCM Replenish',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T12:36:19',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle30',
            vehicleId: 30,
            visitOrder: 1,
          },
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 245814193,
            duration: 1074000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T11:18:01',
            latitude: 41.022554,
            locationCode: 'S1C2293',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'ATM',
            longitude: 29.015923,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117170,
            serviceType: 'Fix',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T11:00:07',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle30',
            vehicleId: 30,
            visitOrder: 2,
          },
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 273658538,
            duration: 444000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T11:32:59',
            latitude: 41.018628,
            locationCode: 'S1C1902',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'ATM',
            longitude: 29.011041,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117169,
            serviceType: 'ATM Replenish',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T11:25:35',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle30',
            vehicleId: 30,
            visitOrder: 3,
          },
          {
            distanceMatrixId: 272746632,
            duration: 618000,
            endDate: '2019-09-24T11:47:01',
            latitude: 41.01522,
            locationCode: 'S1R2650',
            locationName: '',
            locationType: 'RCM',
            longitude: 29.011577,
            planDayId: 183,
            planResultId: 117168,
            serviceType: 'RCM Replenish',
            startDate: '2019-09-24T11:36:43',
            status: 'To Do',
            vehicleCode: 'Vehicle30',
            vehicleId: 30,
            visitOrder: 4,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};

// export interface Datum2 {
//   distanceMatrixId: number;
//   duration: number;
//   endDate: Date;
//   latitude: number;
//   locationCode: string;
//   locationName: string;
//   locationType: string;
//   longitude: number;
//   planDayId: number;
//   planResultId: number;
//   serviceType: string;
//   startDate: string;
//   status: string;
//   vehicleCode: string;
//   vehicleId: number;
//   visitOrder: number;
// }

// export interface GridData {
//   currentPage: number;
//   firstRowOnPage: number;
//   kind: number;
//   lastRowOnPage: number;
//   pageCount: number;
//   pageSize: number;
//   totalRowCount: number;
//   data: Datum2[];
// }

// export interface Datum {
//   id: number;
//   vehicleCode: string;
//   vehicleId: number;
//   color: string;
//   gridData: GridData;
// }

// export interface RootObject {
//   data: Datum[];
// }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-leaflet supports adding [custom controls](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-react-control/). Using such custom control, you can add a basic list that handles selecting a vehicle, saving its index in state and changing the route accordingly.

[Here's a working fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlv3-routing-machine-forked-8bov8i) that places a very basic custom control in the bottom-left corner. This is because once the routing control is appended to the DOM, your top-right corner would be occupied.

Apart from the custom control and `useState()` hook, you'll also want to modify the `useEffect` hook in the `Routing.tsx` to be exhaustive. As for why this is, I recommend giving [Dan Abramov's deep-dive](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#teaching-react-to-diff-your-effects) a read. Basically, with just the map in your deps, your component will never update, even if the underlying coordinates change.
For clarity, I left the `markerBounds` out of the dependency list in the sample. You should see yellow squiggly lines saying the list is missing that (so in your code, you would add it in there)

Also as a side note, although I'm sure this is just for testing purposes, I would advise against re-instantiating the whole routing machine in the `useEffect` hook and rather update the coordinates there and then reroute.
This would remove the need to call `addTo()` and `removeControl()` on every render

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for helping. I would also like to thank you for your detailed explanation and suggestions. I will also read the deep -dive article you suggested.